# Search to return both child items and parent items

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement to allow a search by name ( begins with).
This search will return all items that begin with some letter(s) and all the parents that contain the child items that begin with those letters.

Sample data attached with my attempt to do it.  Is there a better way to do it?  Thank you very much in advance.

```
declare @A table ( ID int ,
                Name varchar(100),
                ParentID int)
INSERT INTO @A Values ( 1, 'Apples', 10)
INSERT INTO @A Values ( 2, 'Bananas', 20)
INSERT INTO @A Values ( 3, 'Mangos ', 30)
INSERT INTO @A Values ( 4, 'Avocados ', 10)
INSERT INTO @A Values ( 5, 'Blueberries ', 20)
INSERT INTO @A Values ( 6, 'Blackberries ', 20)
INSERT INTO @A Values ( 7, 'Apricots ', 10)
INSERT INTO @A Values ( 10, 'Fruits beginning with A ', 0)
INSERT INTO @A Values ( 20, 'Fruits beginning with B ', 0)
INSERT INTO @A Values ( 30, 'Fruits beginning with C ', 0)
-- when searching for A should find Apples, Avocados, Apricots 
-- and 'Fruits beginning with A' (ie their parent).
DECLARE @Letter varchar (10) = 'A%'

select id, name, ParentID from @a 
where name like @Letter 
UNION
select id, name,parentID from @a
where ID  in (select distinct ParentID from @a 
where name like @Letter )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `OR` operator:

```
select id, name,parentID 
from @a
where name like @Letter or
    ID  in (select ParentID from @a 
        where name like @Letter)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using `EXISTS` which has a good execution plan:

```
select id, name,parentID 
from a
where exists (select 1
              from a a2
              where name like @Letter and (a.id = a2.id or a.id=a2.parentid))
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33eb0/9)

Comment: Thank you!  this works for my sample data but on my real life table of prescription drugs it runs a long time.  I will have to run with actual execution plan to see if some index is missing.